# Is a comma needed in a sentence containing two clauses?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Can this sentence be made easier to read?

> "During some of the subjects I had the opportunity to work within a team as during our Science and Physics lessons, we often used to go the school laboratories to do some experiments working as teams of people".

I'm not sure whether getting rid of that comma would make the sentence easier to read or not; what do you think?

Comment: there are bigger problems in this sentence than the comma.

Comment: The comma is not the biggest problem in this sentence. The sentence is what MS Word tends to call ‘run-on’, meaning it’s not very well structured – instead of having a clearly defined structure with clear relationships between the main clause and its subordinate clauses, it is a string of clauses whose relationship to each other is quite nebulous. There are also several things that are not very natural English (“during some of the subjects”, “to do some experiments”, “working as teams of people”). Overall, unfortunately, it is not a very well-written sentence.

Answer (score 2):

What you have here is two sentences, both with their own additional issues.  This is how I would write this instead:

> I had the opportunity to work within a team in several classes.  For example, we often worked together in the school laboratories during Science and Physics.

You don't need to specify that you were working on experiments, it is implied in *laboratories.* You don't need to specify that they were teams *of people*, that's a fairly safe bet to make. Make it simple, have the action come before the location, and write it the way you would say it.

Alternatively, you could replace "for example" with a semicolon, and turn it all into one sentence.  But I would avoid that.  You don't *need* a semicolon here, and they tend to add unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score -2):

> During some of the subjects, I had the opportunity to work in a team, because during our Science and Physics lessons, we often went to the school laboratories working as a team.

That's my thinking. I want say, and some stops, I'm almost out of breath! And I believe you use too many unnecessary dunplicate words.

`often used to`? Why can't we just say often and use past tense?
`teams of people`? Why can't we just say `a team`? Or `teams of people` means there were more than one team since you have so many people? In that case, you can just say `teams`. `teams` certainly made of people, there's no need to mention that, huh?

I'm not quite sure about the meaning of `During some of the subjects`.

To be honest, your sentense reminds my high school time, when we do writting we used extremly complex long sentense with nested clause and rare-used fabulous words to get high scores...

Comment: I had to downvote this answer because the suggestion you give is actually _ungrammatical_. The entire second sentence is not a sentence – it’s a subordinate clause with no main clause. (Additionally, you should not use `code markup` to represent quoted text – there’s a dedicated quote function for that, which doesn’t mess things up for people using screen readers and other assistive technologies.)

Comment: @Janus Feel free to edit the quote style

Comment: Edits are better suited to questions, fixing typos, grammar mistakes etc. But when someone posts an answer, visitors and users alike expect that the answerer is confident of what they're saying. Errors in answers are one of the reasons for downvoting. I also mentioned in a [previous edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/464106/revisions) of mine that backticks should not be used, 1. they look ugly 2. they're for code.  Feel free to ignore Janus's and my advice.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A I'm with cellphone now. Hard to do that. And I don't know the right quoting style. People should be free to edit other people's answer as long as they don't change other people's intension, since that's (actually I think quite unique) functionality this website is providing. Maybe no strictly line defines intension, but correcting wrong quote style should definitely be acceptable.